# The proof of 4 equalities from Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, clustering

I need help with proving of 4 equalities from Combinatorics. Actually, they are quite obvious, but my teacher insists on the complete proof, "step-by-step" proof, but I have some troubles with it...

Given a set of $n$ elements $S=\{o_1, \ldots, o_n\}$ and $2$ partitions: $X = \{X_1, \ldots, X_k\}$ a partition of S into $k$ subsets, and $Y = \{Y_1, \ldots, Y_l\}$ - a partition of S into $l$ subsets.

We define the following:

$A_{11}$ - the number of pairs of elements in $S$ that are in the same subset in $X$ and in the same subset in $Y$

$A_{00}$ - the number of pairs of elements in $S$ that are in different subsets in $X$ and in different subsets in $Y$

$A_{10}$ - the number of pairs of elements in $S$ that are in the same subset in $X$ and in different subsets in $Y$

$A_{01}$ - the number of pairs of elements in $S$ that are in different subsets in $X$ and in the same subset in $Y$

Also we introduce the notations:

$N_{i,j} = |X_{i} \cap Y_{j}|$ - the number of elements into the intersection $X_{i}$ and $Y_{j}$

$A = {n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ - the total number of pairs for $S$

$Q_{X} = \sum_{i}{X_{i} \choose 2}$

$Q_{Y} = \sum_{j}{Y_{j} \choose 2}$

It is needed to prove, that:

1. $A_{11} = \sum_{i,j}{N_{i,j} \choose 2}$
2. $A_{00} = A - Q_{X} - Q_{Y} + A_{11}$
3. $Q_{X} = A_{11} + A_{10}$
4. $Q_{Y} = A_{11} + A_{01}$

Write, please, the proof with all the details!

Sorry for my English.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit this question. Most people won't get the language you have written in one of your statements.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Thanks, Kumar, I have edited it.